# Qual a diferença entre uma string definida dentro de um arquivo texto e outra definida como uma variável?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Imagine o seguinte:

```
texto = "They fly quickly over the snow in their sledges; the motion is pleasant, and, in my opinion, far more agreeable than that of an English stagecoach"

texto1 = open("sample.txt")
```

onde `sample.txt` tem o mesmo conteúdo da variável texto acima

Ao fazer

```
for i in texto:
     print(i)
```

é impresso caractere a caractere.

Ao contrário de:

```
for i in texto1:
     print(i)
```

O texto completo é impresso. Por quê?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A diferença é o tipo do objeto que você está iterando.

No primeiro exemplo o seu laço de repetição está iterando sobre uma *string*, que quando iterado gera como saída os caracteres um a um. Esse comportamento é definido na própria API em C do Python, como especificação da linguagem.

Já no segundo exemplo o laço de repetição está iterando sobre o retorno da função `open`, que é um objeto [*file-like*](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-object); ou seja, um objeto que implementa a classe `io.IOBase`, que devida a sua implementação é um objeto iterável que gera a cada iteração uma linha do conteúdo.

Ou seja, no primeiro você itera apenas sobre uma *string* simples, enquanto no segundo você itera sobre um arquivo, linha a linha. Como o seu arquivo só tem uma linha, o conteúdo inteiro é exibido na primeira iteração.

Para chegar em uma equivalência entre os dois exemplos, no segundo você primeiro deveria carregar todo o conteúdo em memória, na forma de *string*.

```
texto1 = open('sample.txt').read()
# O método read lê o arquivo inteiro

for i in texto1:
    print(i)
```

Comment: Foi mais veloz que eu... :(

Comment: pergutnas fáceis, mas completas em que não precisa dar uma volta  e explicar o básico da programação são coisa em falta por aqui - -fica todo mundo em cima.  :-D

Comment: Mas olha aí, até o jsbueno se manifestou, não era só eu então. :D

Comment: Woss, tu foi muito rápido kkk Ta doido xD

Answer (score 1):

A string definida na variável e a que vem do texto não tem diferença nenhuma.

O que a função `open()` retorna é um objeto de`<class '_io.TextIOWrapper'>`, onde você pode obter a string do arquivo utilizando um desses métodos: `read`, `readline`, `readlines`. Ou seja, o que você obtém desta função, não é uma string !!

Fora isso, esse objeto também é um iterável, e você pode através de *for loop* percorrer cada linha do arquivo. Por isso no seu exemplo, a string é impressa por completo, porque a cada volta que o *for loop* dá, ele devolve uma linha completa do seu arquivo.

Já no exemplo da string que você define na sua variável, ele imprime cada letra pois strings também são objetos iteráveis (sequência) e ao realizar um *for loop* com elas, você obterá em cada volta um elemento da string.

Exemplo:

```
variavel = "Olá!\n Como você está ?"

file = open("arquivo.txt") # Mesmo conteúdo da variável.

for linha in file:
    print("Nova linha:",linha)

    # Já que a variável "linha" é uma string, vamos passar ela em um for loop.

    for letra in linha:
        print("Letra da linha:",letra)

    print("-----------------------------")

file.close()
```

A saída disto será:

```
Nova linha: Olá!

Letra da linha: O
Letra da linha: l
Letra da linha: á
Letra da linha: !
Letra da linha: 

-----------------------------
Nova linha:  Como você está ?
Letra da linha:  
Letra da linha: C
Letra da linha: o
Letra da linha: m
Letra da linha: o
Letra da linha:  
Letra da linha: v
Letra da linha: o
Letra da linha: c
Letra da linha: ê
Letra da linha:  
Letra da linha: e
Letra da linha: s
Letra da linha: t
Letra da linha: á
Letra da linha:  
Letra da linha: ?
-----------------------------
```

Comment: Boa resposta Jean, mas se você me permitir dar um pitaco eu não chamaria sequências nem objetos _file-like_ de "iteradores", mas sim de "iteráveis"... Pois iteradores são objetos a parte, que você recebe usando `iter()`. Você mesmo pode testar no terminal: `type("teste")` resulta em `<class 'str'>`, enquanto `type(iter("teste"))` resulta em `<class 'str_iterator'>`.

Comment: Realmente, eu não tinha pensado nisso. Obrigado, vou corrigir a resposta ;-)